# Can someone help me to understand a sentence by breaking It down to It's elements?

Tags: grammar

Can you help me understand this sentence by breaking down it to its elements. I actually get what it means but I need help to understand the logic behind its grammer. (Tense, Verb Forms etc.)
The sentence is below:

> If he had lived he would have crucified us all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex sentence.

"he would have crucified us all" - this is the main or independent clause

"if he had lived" - it is the subordinate or dependent clause. It cannot form a sentence by itself. It needs the main clause to make sense.

The subordinate clause is here a conditional clause. It gives the condition for the action in the main clause to happen. "Crucification" can happen only if someone "lives". So it is a conditional adverbial clause.

The sentence describes an unreal situation in the past. "he did not live". Hence "he could not crucify us".

Answer (score 0):

`If he had lived, he would have crucified us all.`

If : conditional 
He : subject
had : verb in past simple tense
lived : verb in past participle tense 
, : comma to separate sentences 
he : subject 
would : verb in past tense (used as auxiliary)
have : verb in infinitive tense 
crucified : verb in past participle form 
us : pronoun 
all : pronoun